# Installation-Allocate drive space/Boot Loader

Tags: installation, dual-boot

When I try to install Ubuntu 10.10 from the official livedisc I got in the mail, when I get to the "Allocate Disk Space" step I cannot get it to work.  I shrank my win7 partition so I have unallocated space, then I tried using the space while it is formatted in NTFS, but the partitions will not show up in the box.  /dev/sda is selected under boot loader, and I can't select anything else, but the partition box is blank so when I click "install ubuntu" it just says:  "No root file system is defined. Please correct this from the partitioning menu."

-I am trying to dual-boot win7 and ubuntu, but I was never asked in the install process whether I would like to install just ubuntu or dual-boot?

Comment: You chose manual partitioning and the box does not show /dev/sda?

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal

type:

```
sudo apt-get remove dmraid
```

then type "y" then enter"

This TOTALLY worked. I did it all from 10.10 cd. Must be some RAID code interfering with the install - the new installation is terrible. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. It is from http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8225121&postcount=1 . Go to the bottom and read the following: "Ultimate solution:

Boot up 9.10 Live CD

Open a terminal

type: `sudo apt-get remove dmraid`

then type "y" then enter

now try to install!" This solved my problem and hopefully for all of you folks also!

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! This did work, I did this and was able to install 10.10 successfully with the Live CD.

Answer (score -1):

i guess you are doing it wrong. dont install ubuntu without reading the manual for advanced partition. you will end up deleting win 7 altogether!
check this tutotrial.

http://www.howtoplaza.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-904-on-a-manually-created-partition

it is based on ubuntu 9.04 but idea is the same. you need to create 2 partitions. one for swap and another for root. check the screenshots in that tutorial. if u still have confusion, come back and post q's again.

Comment: When I try to install it, it never shows me this step http://www.ubuntu.com/sites/default/files/active/maverick/install_03_medium.jpg I don't get the option of how I want to install it, instead it goes to a screen where it wants to prepare the partitions, but doesn't show the partitions.  http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_JBHfzEovWs8/TMWkviQT0VI/AAAAAAAAAxE/cwkjHm_JvTA/s1600/7ubuntu10.10install-swappartitioncreated.png this is what it brings me to instead of showing me that step, but the bar at the top is empty, the box is empty, and I can't select anything besides /dev/sda